# Ubuntu 12.04 Mysql doesn't start on reboot; starts ok later manually

Tags: 12.04, boot, mysql, services

I've just installed MySql to support a mediawiki install on 12.04 64bit.
Everything appears to be working ok, except that at boot-up, mysql server fails to start.
This results in an error appearing on the webpage:

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

When I discover this, and run

```
sudo service mysql start
```

It all works ok after that until the next reboot.

I can't figure out what is going on.

There appear to be several similar issues being reported, however most of these appear to be outright failure to start - i.e. manual start or on boot-up fails.
I haven't seen anything relating to a "transient" error like this.

For the record, I've got a fairly standard install - I didn't fiddle with settings - just the bind address in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
I thought maybe something to do with drive mounting, but datadir is on `/var` which is on the main partition.

any clues? Suggestions even for a workaround?

Only workaround I'm toying with is to set a cronjob at intervals of every half hour or so.

Comment: What erros do you see on your mysql.log, like in /var/log/mysql...

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't particularly helpful with my information...  I did check /var/log/mysql.log and mysql.err - both empty.  I also know that the service attempts to start because in dmesg, it shows messages saying post-start process terminating with status 1.  I will need to get the actual messages later - I don't have access to them right now.

Comment: Can you post here the output of the logs of mysql?

Comment: Are there logs other than in /var/log?  These were empty.

Comment: Don't you have something like /var/log/mysql.* ?

Comment: I checked both /var/log/mysql.log and /var/log/mysql.err.  Both were empty.

Comment: And you have mysql running?

Comment: mysql doesn't start at bootup, so no, it's not running.  I can start it manually after bootup successfully, but I figure if there was stuff in the log after manually starting, that it would not help diagnosing the fault.

Comment: The log for starting mysql is in /var/log/syslog. You can filter it with `cat /var/log/syslog | grep mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem was....
my dodgy router...

Our modem/router as a bad FW build on it (which I'm working on separately) which requires rebooting several times a day.  This meant that often at bootup in the morning, the router would be "down", and the computer wouldn't even be able to get an IP address.

That IP address is a fixed address assigned by the router, and is set as the "bind address" in mysql configuration file ("my.cnf")

I haven't tested my theory properly, but I have noticed that sometimes it works at bootup and sometimes not.  And I definitely know that it fails to start if the bind address is wrong - exhibiting the same sorts of failure messages in dmesg.

Thanks all for responding!

Comment: If you bind mysql address in my.cnf (or for any services/daemons your machine acts as a server), you should use a fixed IP on it and leave the router out of this matter. This way even if your router "feels lazy or gets mad", your server will have the right IP.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL service is probably not enabled at boot.

Try `sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults` and reboot.

Comment: Hi Marc - see my comments from above - it appears to be attempting to start, looking at dmesg, but reports "post-start process terminating with status 1" (plus a couple of other messages).